# Администрирование новостей

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cms

[image: Управление новостями]

Как сделать так чтобы при добавлении новости старые новости съезжали на другой блок как указано на скриншоте по стрелочкам. И последний блок с самой старой новостью на странице переходил на вторую страницу на которую можно перейти под новостями (1 2 3 4 ... 9). 
Дополнительные вопросы:
1. Можно ли натянуть такой шаблон новостей на какую-нибудь простую CMS (Wordpress например). 
2. Нужно ли иметь навыки в php для этого.
3. И легче ли написать простую админ-панель для управления новостями.
Прошу напишите как это реализовать, что необходимо знать и как это легче сделать. Благодарю)

Comment: 1) да 2) да 3) не легче, но в любом случае вопрос - как вы напишете свою панель без навыков в php?

Comment: В твоём случае легче и правильнее - обратиться к специалистам для изготовления сайта.